# Как правильно: "станет возможно" или "станет возможным"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

**Станет возможно получать новые данные...**

Как правильно: *"станет **возможно**"* или *"станет **возможным**"*? Является ли в данном случае написание вариативным?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обе формы возможны: **Станет возможно/возможным получать новые данные.**

Здесь инфинитив в роли подлежащего, сказуемое составное именное, именная часть выражена наречием "возможно" или  субстантивным словом ср.рода "возможное" в  форме Т.п.

Форма "станет возможным" вообще используется чаще, чем "станет возможно" (частотность 125:20), так как Т.п. обычно обозначает непостоянный, меняющийся признак.

Примеры:

«После того как **станет возможным** делать хирургические нанооперации на клеточном уровне, можно будет взять человека из криостаза, медленно согреть его, и тогда он снова будет жить» 2010]

А напряжение от необходимости многолетнего молчания и бездействия никуда не исчезало,  поджидая своего часа, когда **станет возможно** наконец-то все сказать. 
[«Техника - молодежи», 1989]